# Function overload compilation error (This overload signature is not compatible) with template literal types

Tags: typescript

I have a function that takes a date format string (e.g., `"YYYY-MM-DD"` or `"YYYY"`) and returns a template literal type based on that format. The following code is a minimal example:

```js
type ISODate = `${number}-${number}-${number}`;
type Year = `${number}`;

type ISOFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD";
type YearFormat = "YYYY";

function format(f: ISOFormat): ISODate;
function format(f: YearFormat): Year;
function format(f: ISOFormat | YearFormat) {
  if (f === "YYYY-MM-DD") {
    return "1234-12-12";
  }
  return "1234";
}
```

However, I get a compilation error ([Typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgygeQCIENjQLxQAYBIDeAdgK4C2ARhAE4C+AtASRdfY2ZbTdgNwBQokKAE0IKKlCx4i7Fj179w0eAgBiAeyqk0EqACIhBoXQCyxukiS6+A6CLHrN2rPsNX5AM2KEAxsACWaoRQ7hpawAAU7gBcsIgOYQCUMcqo6HyePv6BwaFokTF2VPFoScKiVOlevgFBIY4R0bGqucBQAD5l9i0JUPi8UFB+7lCREhjOhkam5pY9fQMDVBDAxFRB2ACMAEwAzAAsdNuHW3IDNP1QSytrONv7cudAA)):

> This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature.

What I find really odd is the compilation error goes away when I change either of my return values to a template literal. For example ([Typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgygeQCIENjQLxQAYBIDeAdgK4C2ARhAE4C+AtASRdfY2ZbTdgNwBQokKAE0IKKlCx4i7Fj179w0eAgBiAeyqk0EqACIhBoXQCyxukiS6+A6CLHrN2rPsNX5AM2KEAxsACWaoRQ7hpawAAU7gBcsIgOYQCUMcqo6HyePv6BwaFokTF2VPFoScKiVOlevgFBIY4R0bGqucBQAD5l9i0JUPi8UFB+7lCREhjOhkam5pY9fQMDVBDAxFRB2ACMAEwAzAAsdNuHW3IDNP1QSytrOAQbNLt7cudAA)):

```js
type ISODate = `${number}-${number}-${number}`;
type Year = `${number}`;

type ISOFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD";
type YearFormat = "YYYY";

function format(f: ISOFormat): ISODate;
function format(f: YearFormat): Year;
function format(f: ISOFormat | YearFormat) {
  if (f === "YYYY-MM-DD") {
    return "1234-12-12";
  }
  return `${1}234`;
}
```

Can anyone help me understand why the former example has a compilation error but the latter compiles just fine?

Comment: What's going on with `${number}${number}${number}${number}`?  That can't be what you mean; `${number}` matches any string representation of a number, like `"2"` or `"1.23"`.  So `${number}${number}${number}${number}` means "the concatenation of four string representations of numbers", like, uh `"3.141.2399.99-3.5"`.  That's not what you intend, right?

Comment: Oh yeah, that's a pretty dumb mistake. My intent was something like a four-digit number, but now I realize that's clearly not going to enforce four digits. (I guess it'll enforce no fewer than four digits...)

Comment: I'm inclined to close this out; however, I'd still be interested in why this is happening. Even if the types were `\`${number}-${number}-${number}\`` and `\`${number}\`` respectively, it seems the compilation error still happens

Comment: Yeah, you might want to keep it open, but perhaps change it to a [mcve] that doesn't have this particular issue

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I removed the weird typing that obfuscated the real issue.

Comment: I think an [mcve] might be [this](https://tsplay.dev/m026nw); the compiler seems to be unhappy that your actual implementation is inferred to return fewer possibilities than the call signature return types.  I'm not sure why this is a problem, but you can fix it with an explicit implementation return type annotation.  I suspect that the reason why `\`${1}234\`` makes it work is that the compiler can no longer easily see that the implementation is returning "too few possibilities".  I'm still looking into it.

Comment: ugh, well I can't easily locate why the compiler cares about things like this.. I might open a GitHub issue to find out, if I get the chance.  I'm happy to make an answer with the above info, but I don't know if it's helpful enough.

Comment: Thank you for looking into it! Interestingly, it seems like the compiler isn't happy with the solution to the minimum reproducible example [when applied to my initial question example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgygeQCIENjQLxQAYBIDeAdgK4C2ARhAE4C+AtASRdfY2ZbTdgNwBQokKAE0IKKlCx4i7Fj179w0eAgBiAeyqk0EqACIhBoXQCyxukiS6+A6CLHrN2rPsNX5AM2KEAxsACWaoRQ7hpawAAU7gBcsIgOYQCUMcqo6HyePv6BwaFokTF2VPFoScKiVOlevgFBIY4R0bGqucBQAD5l9i2lKWjQHYVQ+LxQUH7uUJESGM6GRqbmlglDI6NQVBDAxFRB2ACMAEwAzAAsdIfnB3KjNKsbWzs4h6dyt0A).

Comment: because your `ISODate` type has an extra `}` in it?

Comment: Sigh, I've taken up enough of your time >.<. I agree that the solution you proposed works; it does seem like it's a matter of explicitly typing the return type of the function implementation. Feel free to make that the answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here seems to be that the compiler sees the call signature's return type as *too wide* for the implementation.  The implementation signature is inferred to return `"1234-12-12" | "1234"`.  But one of the call signatures is claiming to be able to return `ISODate`, a much wider type that does not completely subsume `"1234-12-12" | "1234"`.  Why the compiler cares about this is not clear to me.  On the off chance that this is a bug in TypeScript, I've filed [microsoft/TypeScript#44661](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44661).  At the very least we should get word back that this *isn't* a bug and why.

**UPDATE:** According to [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44661#issuecomment-865142074), the current behavior isn't a bug, but the intent was to prevent completely incorrect return types like `"1234"` alone for `ISODate`.  They are taking the report as a suggestion to allow call signature return types that merely *overlap* with the implementation return type as opposed to being a supertype-or-subtype.

---

Anyway, my suggestion here is to explicitly [annotate the return type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#return-type-annotations) of the function implementation to be the union of all the call signature return types.  Then the compiler will see each call signature as compatible with it, while checking that the implementation is also compatible with the signature:

```
function format(f: ISOFormat): ISODate; // okay
function format(f: YearFormat): Year;
function format(f: ISOFormat | YearFormat): ISODate | Year {
  if (f === "YYYY-MM-DD") {
    return "1234-12-12";
  }
  return "1234";
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgygeQCIENjQLxQAYBIDeAdgK4C2ARhAE4C+AtASRdfY2ZbdgNwBQokUAJoQUVKFjxF2Lbjz7ho8BADEA9lVJpxUAESD9gugFkjdJEh29+0YaLUatWPQctyAZsUIBjYAEtVhFBu6prAABRuAFywiPahAJTRSqjovB7efgFBIWgR0bZUcWiJQiJUaZ4+-oHBDuFRMSo5wFAAPqV2zSXJaNDtBVD4PFBQvm5QEeIYTgaGJmYW8YPDI1BUEMDEVIE6AIwATADMACx0B2f7riM0K+ub27oHJ640QA)

Comment: Awesome analysis, thank you. The solution to explicitly annotate the return type does work and I look forward to following the issue you filed.

Comment: Updated with info on the GitHub issue